# Understanding derivatives in simple terms

Tags: integration, derivatives, probability-distributions, soft-question, mathematical-physics

Im am trying to understand the idea of derivatives and how they relate to the real world.

I understand if i have function, in pkysics first derivative is the velocity, and the second derivative is the acceleration. My question is are there any other physical or theoretical applications of the derivatives that are similar. I ask also if i can apply this to probability, and in particular what is the relationship between the probability densitiy function and cumulative distribution

Comment: The first derivative of the distance you drove with respect to time is the speed. The second derivative of the distance, that is to say the derivative of the speed is acceleration. Do you want we satrt with these ?

Comment: Do you have any additional relationships in the world of probability?

Comment: I am too bad in that specific area (as well as in many other) to answer this question. I was trying to answer the first sentence of your post. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability density function is the first derivative of the cumulative distribution. So that gives you an application of derivatives in probability.

If you aren't familiar with Taylor series yet, that is another very important application of derivatives (all derivatives of every order) so that you can approximate a smooth function by a polynomial, to arbitrary accuracy as you let the degree of the polynomial increase.

Comment: Thank you, do any further derivatives of the probabilities make any sense? i.e what is the derivative of the density function?

Comment: @MathsPro

There are some applications in probability where you can approximate a function of a distribution in terms of derivatives, for example if the original function is a tight Gaussian so that the new function applied to the Gaussian can be approximated locally in the high density region of the Gaussian as a linear transformation of the Gaussian (hence Gaussian), where the linear transformation is given in terms of derivatives.